# Unload/unreference a referenced assembly from F# interactive

Tags: f#, assemblies, f#-interactive

The F# Interactive (fsi.exe) has a directive to reference a given assembly:

```
>#help;;
   [...]
   #r "file.dll";;        Reference (dynamically load) the given DLL
   [...]
```

I often like to unload/unreference previously referenced assemblies in order to recompile them. Is that possible?

**Edit:** I'm running fsi under MacOSX and Mono - should be the same as from command line under windows.

Comment: if it loads with the regular Assembly.Load, then I guess not: http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/07/08/57211.aspx

Comment: That does not look promising... but thank you.

Comment: Unless the FSI implementation is very naive, all dynamic assembly loading will be performed in a sandboxed AppDomain, which can be unloaded. You won't be able to unload individual assemblies though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right click and select **Reset Session**. But obviously this clears everything, not just your references.

Comment: I am under MacOSX and mono so I don't really have that alternative... but it seems like you're right - reseting the session is the only solution... :(

Comment: #quit;; will stop the session, allowing you to press enter to restart the session.